# U.K. visa refusal and 10 year ban (false documents). Can I apply while the ban is in effect?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, visa-bans

I was banned for 10 years in 2009 when I applied for UK business visitor visa. I was a travel agent and my franchise had expired 3 months before and I was in process of renewing it. I applied for visa and got rejected for false information as I no longer had a franchise.

Can I now apply for a visitor visa without contesting the ban. It's been 8 years already. What are the chances?

Comment: We can't take bets on your chances, ti's too open-ended. But take care to avoid bogus agents who claim they can get you a visa you do not qualify for. As a banned person you are vulnerable to visa scam operators. Upstairs, downstairs, under the bed, everywhere.

Comment: Related http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64097/what-can-i-do-to-lift-a-10-year-ban-for-making-a-mistake-in-my-uk-visa-applicati

Comment: I don't understand. Which part of the phrase "banned for ten years" do you think means you can enter the UK eight years later?

Answer (score 14):

Zero. A ban is a ban. It's not yet 2019. I do not even understand the question. Also note that after the ban expires they will be incredibly suspicious and it'll be very, very hard for you to get a visa into the UK again. If you are willing to make life altering decisions based on the crazy ramblings of a random Internet stranger then try to organize the rest of your life in a way that doesn't include entering the UK.