# Can intended date of travel be changed during appointment for UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, sri-lankan-citizens

I am Sri Lankan and am currently applying for a UK Standard Visitor visa. My problem is that the intended date of travel, which I put in my application, and my visa appointment date to submit the documents for visa approval are the same, the 10th of January 2017.

Will this be a problem for me to get my visa?

Comment: I can't possibly see this as a problem. Not a big one and not a little one. Lots of people want to travel ASAP.  If it's bugging you, then see if you qualify for priority service. But given what you've written, there's no apparent problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

The premise for your visit may be relevant.

IMO if going for say a week's vacation then it should not be a big problem.

On the other hand if going for a conference (say week long and commencing 11/1/17) then it probably would be a big problem because you are clearly not going to make that in time, and the premise for your visa is no longer valid. That being so you would need a new premise and hence a new assessment and hence a new application.

See [also](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/84454/4995).

Equivalent issue for [Schengen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/71628/4995).