# I answered incorrectly to "Have you ever been refused a visa?" in my UK Tier 4 visa application form

Tags: visas, uk, student-visas

I made a huge mistake. My application is submitted and biometrics are done. Application is on it's way to UKVI. I answered "No" when I should have answered "Yes". In 2015, I was refused a residence permit to study in Denmark because the school I applied to wasn't approved by a government authority. I didn't know that it wasn't a government affiliated or approved school, and applied anyway. There was nothing wrong with my application though.

While filling out my UK Tier 4 application, I completely forgot about this. It was an honest mistake. What should I do? Should I contact UKVI? I have already got admission in a HEI in London and attached my CAS and everything with the documents.
P.S - I'm from India.

Comment: There's an answer [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/84447/incorrectly-answered-no-to-any-previous-visa-refusals-on-a-uk-standard-vi) but I am not sure if it's up to date.

Comment: But my application is already on it's way to UKVI. I can't make changes on the printed application form :(

Comment: The answer there addresses this with "You are at the biometric enrolment stage. At that stage the application is 'frozen' into their database and there's nothing you can do about it."  So if that answer is correct then there is indeed nothing you can do about your current situation.

Comment: So I should just wait it out? I shouldn't contact UKVI?

Comment: I can't answer that.  I'm only pointing to you to the information this site has so far.  I don't know of my own knowledge whether it's correct or not.

Comment: @Aburjwal The answer in the linked question is up to date. However since you’ve already given biometrics you only have two options: allow the application to proceed and hope that it’s not refused or cancel it, forfeit the fee and resubmit with the correct information https://www.gov.uk/cancel-visa The latter is preferable IMHO, the likelihood of a refusal (and a ban for deception) is probably very high.

Comment: @Traveller (in support of your comment) the problem with allowing the application to go forward is that if its discovered at a later date, the penalty and outcome might be harsher (ie if they need to apply for another UK visa and its come to light then, a ban would severely affect studies or personal life in the UK for example) - the only sensible option here is, imho, withdraw the application, amend the application and reapply.

Comment: @Moo But hasn't a UK govt published a guideline about 'innocent mistakes' recently? https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/850831/false-representation-v2.0.pdf
Where they say that if an ECO alleges deception or false representation the burden of proof is on HO to show that it was ACTUALLY deception? I'm just asking if there is any chance for me, since a lot of money is involved in re-applying.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incorrectly answered 'No' to "Any previous visa refusals..." on a UK Standard Visitor visa application. How can I fix my mistake?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/84447/incorrectly-answered-no-to-any-previous-visa-refusals-on-a-uk-standard-vi)

Comment: @Aburjwal the forms are pretty clear about whats being asked, so its pretty easy to show deception in these sort of cases.  The OP knows the application is not a true representation, and its possible that leaving off a visa refusal has a material effect on the decision, so to go ahead with the application now would not be an "innocent mistake", it would be false representation in the applicants favour.  The examples given in that document do not fit the situation the OP is in - its not a typo, or a misplaced figure, its the absence of some material information to a specific question.

Comment: @Moo - What if I informed the HO via email? Will that help? If I disclose the entire situation?

Comment: Were you refused a residence permit or a visa? I suspect there is some room to truthfully claim that you were not refused a visa, if it wasn't a visa...

Comment: @user253751 I was refused a residence permit

Comment: In my opinion, what happened to you in Denmark in 2015 isn't the UK's business. Furthermore, since the question doesn't give a scope, I would interpret the question as "have you been denied a Visa by the UK".  Lastly, a residence permit isn't a Visa. Being denied a Visa by a state means you're not allowed to visit there, period. If you're permitted to visit, but not to reside, you have not been denied a Visa.

Comment: @Kaz Actually the question covers everything - visa, long term leave to stay or remain, deportation etc. So I think a refusal of residence permit would be covered. However I do hope that they don't care much about a Denmark refusal, especially since it wasn't because of faulty documentation from my side.