# I emailed UKVI regarding my mistake in reporting previous refusals. What does their reply mean for my application?

Tags: visas, uk

This is in continuation to this question: [I answered incorrectly to "Have you ever been refused a visa?" in my UK Tier 4 visa application form](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158822/i-answered-incorrectly-to-have-you-ever-been-refused-a-visa-in-my-uk-tier-4-v)

I emailed UKVI and informed them that I made a mistake. I disclosed all details of my refusal and offered to share the refusal letter if they ask for it. I received a pretty generic reply:

> Dear X,
>
> Thank you for contacting UK Visas and Immigration International
> Contact Centre.
>
> With regards to your enquiry, I can confirm your Visa application is
> awaiting a decision.   Filling out the visa application correctly is
> your responsibility.   After biometrics, you won't able to change any
> information and  application will be under processing.
>
> Regards,
> Abul
> UK Visas and Immigration

So what does this mean? I had requested them to share this info with the concerned ECO. I don't know if they will. But can they still claim deception after I sent an email? If it gets refused, can I say that I tried to disclose my mistake in my administrative review?

Comment: In Denmark, visa related data is stored in the Schengen-wide VIS database for five years. The authorities in the UK do not have direct access to this data (you can make FOI requests to the UK and Denmark to confirm this). It's good that you sent an email but the chance of a refusal for deception on your current application is close to zero. You should have contacted a professional rather than rely on online advice before sending that email.

Comment: @uberqe I did talk to a few solicitors. Almost all of them advised me to send an email describing how I got a refusal.

Comment: Can you withdraw the application at this point?

Comment: @uberqe You write above "It's good that you sent an email but the chance of a refusal for deception on your current application is close to zero." This makes no sense: the OP made a significant error. The result won't be a "close to zero" chance of refusal for deception, but instead a "close to unity" chance of refusal. The "close to zero" chance would be for success of the flawed application, not refusal.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica No. Schengen refusals are only stored for five years. The UK has no direct access to these records anyways. The risk of the decision-maker finding out about the refusal in Denmark is close to zero. You can make FOI requests to Denmark and the UK yourself if you have any questions about what data is shared. It's free. And the authorities are required to provide this information by law.

Comment: @uberqe The lawyer in me notes that "no direct access" is not necessarily the same as "no access." I do not dispute your assertion about the UK's lack of direct access to old Schengen refusals, but...I'd not be shocked to learn that UKVI learns things indirectly, or even keeps records when they're not supposed to.

Comment: @gktscrk “Anecdotal evidence that can be read easily accessed online mostly seems to fall against my personal experience though“. Possibly because those who have a positive experience don’t post about it online

Comment: @uberque Are refusals recorded in the applicant’s passport as well as in the Schengen database?

Comment: @Traveller I have a stamp by the Denmark Embassy in my passport. It's not a refusal stamp but more of a "visa processed" stamp

Comment: @Aburjwal That changes things. The visa processed stamp is a defacto refusal stamp. The ECO will know about your refusal from the stamp. If the stamp outright said "refusal," your omission would automatically have counted as an innocent mistake (court cases/guidance). However, a "visa processed" stamp can go either way--the ECO will need to determine whether he believes this was intentional deception. Obviously, your email mitigates the risk significantly.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Admitting to keeping records they are not allowed to or obtaining information from sources they are not allowed to may lead to civil (and even criminal) proceedings for violating data protection legislation. Sometimes, they may know certain things but will not use that as a basis for a decision unless that information can be obtained from another source as well. You will be surprised how little agencies within the UK share among themselves. Data protection is a good thing. Unfortunately, it's taken from granted in immigration law/policy because they have no votes.

Comment: @uberqe Yes it depends on the ECO now, I think. I'm keeping my fingers crossed that they don't see it as deception. Although everyone here seems to think I'm get a refusal without a doubt (and even a 10 year ban)

Answer (score 17):

> So what does this mean?

They rejected your request to submit more information for your application.  Your application will be judged on its merits based on the information submitted at the time biometrics were taken.

> I had requested them to share this info with the concerned ECO. I
> don't know if they will.

They won't, thats quite clear from the answer you received, specifically this line:

> ***After biometrics, you won't able to change any information and application will be under processing.***

> But can they still claim deception after I sent an email?

Possibly, but the email might be judged to be fair evidence that your mistake was innocent, and it also might not be.  No one knows until it's reviewed in an appeal.

> If it gets refused, can I say that I tried to disclose my mistake in my administrative review?

You certainly can, but whether it affects any administrative review outcome is not something that can be judged here unfortunately.

**Edit to add (based on comment discussions):**  The OP has two choices here - proceed with the application and hope everything comes out fine in the end, or withdraw the application, amend it and resubmit it.

The merits of each are very different - withdrawing the application, amending it and resubmitting it has the ***lowest risk*** (no risk of a rejection because of missing information), but ***highest immediate cost*** in that they have to pay the application fees again (as they are withdrawing after biometrics have been taken) and no long term risk.

Proceeding with the application on the other end has a ***lower immediate cost*** (they've already paid the application fees for the current application), but ***higher immediate risk*** (rejection for missing information) and ***still higher long term risk and cost*** (a ban and the cost of mounting an appeal - which is far more than an application fee).

Even if the attempt to supply more information is taken into account during any appeal, there will be a monetary cost attached to that appeal which far exceeds the cost of withdrawing and resubmitting.  Even a straight forward appeal can be costly.

Comment: Okay, so I do have a chance at administrative review then?
If they do consider this as an innocent  mistake, they might grant a visa?

Comment: @Aburjwal "Do I have a chance at X" is not something we can answer here - there are no straight yes and no answers to those kind of questions as it always depends on who does the review, who you have representing you etc etc etc.  You could have the best case in the world and your representation could blow it.  You could have the worst case in the world but a $5000 an hour expert representing you who gets it over the finish line.

Comment: @Aburjwal how much would it cost to withdraw and resubmit the application?  What are the potential consequences of failing to do so?

Comment: @Aburjwal I've never heard of this being considered an "innocent mistake". We have all seen many instances of people getting 10 year bans for this. You should withdraw the application immediately.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'll get a 10 year ban for deception despite the fact that I disclosed the necessary information before they made a decision? I read a document on the UK govt website which says that when an ECO claims deception, the burden of proof is on them to prove that the applicant willfully and knowingly hid information.

Comment: @phoog Basically I would have to pay the entire application fee again (=GBP 348)

Comment: @Aburjwal But you didn't disclose the information! It's not in your application and it is too late to make changes to it.

Comment: @Aburjwal You signed the application stating it was truthful. I don't think they need to prove anything else, unfortunately.

Comment: @mkennedy I think there is a difference between a mistake and willful deception. In any case, if they do refuse my visa I'll have grounds to challenge it in administrative review. I do understand that there is a chance of refusal, but to expect a 10 year ban is paranoia.

Comment: @mkennedy They need to prove that the representation was false AND deception was intended. The guidance is available here: https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/850831/false-representation-v2.0.pdf

Comment: Leaving aside the letter of the law here, if the examiner finds that you "forgot" that you were refused a visa, which presumably was an important event in your life at the time, it is perfectly reasonable for him/her to wonder how many other statements on your application are things that you also "forgot." Don't expect any stones to be left unturned!

Comment: @Aburjwal IMHO it might well have been better to cancel the application and resubmit with the correct information about your previous refusal. You would have incurred a second application fee, but that could have been less than the cost of paying an immigration lawyer to help you deal with a refusal appeal

Comment: @uberqe I read that guidance and commented on it on the other linked question - I personally do not think it fits here, as it doesnt fall into the category of things used as an example.

Comment: The problem with “wilful deception” and “innocent mistake” is that the UK is a highly coveted destination for a lot of people who are more than willing to leave off material information that potentially damages their application if included and later claim its an innocent mistake, and only include it when called out on it.  This isnt the case here, the OP is trying to rectify the situation so that would stand good stead in any appeal, but once the refusal has been issued its a *massive* and very costly uphill battle from that point onward @Aburjwal

Comment: @alephzero Yes it is perfectly reasonable for them to wonder that and they may carry out verification checks to confirm the information in the form. They will find out that all of it is true. It might take some time but at least my application won't be rejected.

Comment: @Aburjwal Please let us know how it goes

Comment: @Aburjwal Moo's comments above are correct, and your "At least my application won't be rejected" is wishful thinking. While you disclosed the prior application information, you did only after giving your biometrics. Remember: they expressly said that after biometrics were taken, the application is locked and no further information or change can be entertained. For the reasons discussed in these comments, it is unfortunately extremely likely that your application will be rejected, and your path thereafter will be uphill, expensive, with a far from certain result.

Comment: @Moo Very nicely stated.

Comment: @Moo, very informative. I experienced something similar in my recent UK visitor visa application, in that I forgot to mention a very important detail; the difference though was that I was able to remember it before I submitted my biometrics. So, I withdrew that application, sought a refund for it, lodged a new one and made sure I read and re-read the form before finalizing it. It was a lot of work and it was costly, but I thought I could always earn the money back but I would not get back my pristine immigration record as I have not had a visa refusal in the past.