# Can someone who an agent applied for UK visiting visa with 10yrs ban without disclosing to the client appeal

Tags: uk, international-travel, visa-bans

An agent applied for my sister and her daughter for UK tourism visa which the agent used a falsified account documents for them without her consent in other to fast track his job. The application Landed them 10yrs ban which he didn't disclose to her, he went ahead a fortify another refusal letter without 10yrs ban and presented to her.unknowingly of the 10yrs ban,she applied for same uk student visa on a priority rate the following year and made 65% tution fee, immediately her documents got to the decision making center, she was refused automatically and reference was made to the last year 10yrs ban which got her confused but later knew it was the reality. Please can she get an immigration lawyer to appeal on her behalf to grant her UK visa for the study, and will it be granted. Thanks

Comment: When did all this happen? What did the refusal letter say (it would help if you uploaded a copy of it, with personal details redacted). There is some information on appeals here https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101247/uk-visa-refused-under-3-6-a-of-appendix-v-deception Note: if she manages to get an immigration lawyer to take on her case it will be expensive with no guarantee of success.

Comment: How much money do you have that you can waste on this?  Because you are going to need a very very good UK-based lawyer for even a chance at succeeding, and thats going to cost you tens of thousands of British pounds.  My advice is to go elsewhere for your further education.

Comment: Also note that submission of a false document is sufficient for an application to be refused, independently of whether the applicant knew the document to be false.

Comment: In addition to what Travellers comments - it doesnt matter that the agent lied and not you, they lied on your behalf and you would have needed to sign that application stating its true and correct.  You signed something that wasnt true and correct…. There isnt much leeway here from UK immigration Im afraid, you are expected to ensure the application is truthful otherwise the standard application would be a falsified one followed by an appeal based on “my agent lied without my knowledge, its not my fault, I should have a do over”.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do to lift a 10 year ban for making a mistake in my UK visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64097/what-can-i-do-to-lift-a-10-year-ban-for-making-a-mistake-in-my-uk-visa-applicati)

Comment: Does 'fortify' mean 'falsify'? If the agent falsified the 10-year ban letter to make it look like a plain refusal, is that a fraud that is actionable within your own country?

Comment: Applicant no longer sign in UK visa application. You just submit all information once done. The mistake she did was to entrust all the process in the agent because it's his field but it's just so unfortunate when we entrust our affairs in the wrong hands

Comment: @HameenatLawal I guarantee there is going to be a checkbox in there which affirms that you say its all true and correct. Doesnt have to be a physical signature.

Comment: I think you should ask a lawyer. Are you sure she had no suspect of the agent? (or in other words: why did she choose to have an agent?) In any case, she must have signed the final document. So, either she is also responsible not checking the documents, or the signature is counterfeit. In such case you should sue the agent, and then ask UK to remove the ban.

Comment: @HameenatLawal thinking about it, you are actually lucky you didnt get dragged into the other side of the "visa agent fraud" that we see here - the visa agent coming back to you saying you'd been rejected but for a fee they can appeal for you, with further fees escalating up as the appeal gets accepted by various UK courts over the course of a few months.  Ultimately, the appeals never existed, you are out a lot of money, and you still dont have a visa.

Comment: I suppose that it is possible the agent managed to alter or add to the application at some point after getting a signature (virtual or otherwise).

Comment: @WeatherVane I think he means "forge".