# What will happen my visa after attemp 17 years

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

In 2005 I was invited Girl Guide camp in UK. They submit two times visa applications.
But visa was rejected. I did not received any in written. Only one line by a pen on the stamp in passport,
Now year 2022, visa submit by a solicitor company for me and family for Tier 02 visa. But I couldn't state previous visa rejection.
Please can you tell me is it affect my this time visa.

Thank you

Comment: Your statement "But I couldn't state previous visa rejection" is not clear. Do you mean you cannot explain _why_ you were rejected in 2005? Even if you do not know the reason for the previous rejection, you should answer "Yes" when you are asked about a prior UK visa refusal, including all the information you have (the year, and that the proposed visit was for a Girl Guide camp). UKVI will know about the prior rejection; answering "No"will be seen as deception in the current application. Being seen as deceptive will result in denial of this application, and possibly a long-term ban.

Comment: To be 100% clear, did you answer ‘No’ to the question about previous visa refusals, when the correct answer is ‘Yes’? If you did, see eg https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101247/uk-visa-refused-under-3-6-a-of-appendix-v-deception After such a long time a prior refusal(s) might not have jeopardised a Tier2 application, whereas lying about the refusal can result in a whole lot of trouble