# Error in UK application, withdrawal of the application

Tags: visas, uk

I applied for UK Visa, first time and it got rejected, now when I applied for the second time, I made a mistake accidently by not mentioning the refusal and I cancelled the application by calling them, however they told me that I will get the emails within the next few weeks but they told me that application is withdrawn and also given me the reference number.
Is my application canceled?
Now If I have to apply for the third time, should I write yes in false information section or how do I explain this?

Comment: How long ago was the refusal? What has changed in your personal circumstances since then to address the reason(s) for the refusal? When you ticked ‘no’ to the question about previous refusals, did you also accidentally forget to fill in the accompanying details section? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101247/uk-visa-refused-under-3-6-a-of-appendix-v-deception

Answer (score 2):

They already have the information about your past refusals in front of them, of course. Although you withdrew the application, you did still make the application in the first place - you signed it and everything - so this is still likely a “false information” case, and not something you shouldn’t mention. Bringing it up gives you a chance to explicitly say it was a mistake and to point out that you voluntarily withdrew the application.

But do not take that advice; it doesn’t matter. Applying again after a second refused visa is not a DIY situation. You should be contacting a *REPUTABLE* immigration attorney (not a “service”, not an “agent”, but someone who is officially *licensed to practice UK law*). They will advise you on the best approach, which (depending on the circumstances of the previous refusal) will likely include “wait a few years first”.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I wasn't refused a visa the second time, I withdrew the application, so I will write "YES" in that section and explain with a note that I realized the error made by me, would that work?

Comment: @traveller2 Yes, it’s nearly always better to mention and explain things than to skip over them, particularly when the examiner will find out about them regardless. Let them decide whether it’s important; but don’t make it look like you’re trying to conceal anything.

Comment: also, How to check that my visa application is canceled, they told me via paid enquiry that is withdrawn now but I haven't received any mail as of now, how long does it take? do you have idea?

Comment: @traveller2 You’ll know within 28 days, which is the time period for a refund of your application fee https://www.gov.uk/cancel-visa