# My family's UK visitor visa was denied 14 years ago, but was approved on appeal. Do I need to mention this in my UK visitor visa application?

Tags: visas, uk

My father applied for a UK visitor visa around 14 years ago for our entire family, when we wanted to visit the UK to attend a wedding ceremony of a relative. He was the main applicant and I was listed as one of his dependents on the visa. However, our visa was approved when our relative(who we were staying with in the UK) appealed the decision.

I am now applying for a visitor visa to the UK, and wanted to confirm the following:

- Since my father's visa was approved on appeal, does this still mean that technically is visa was denied?
- Since I was not the main applicant and was only listed as the dependent, does this initial denial apply to me too? Also, should I mention this in my UK visitor visa application?

Comment: You can mention it and explain. It won't affect your current application in any way

Comment: This [advice](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/110912/118049) should likely be applied