# Schengen visa after appeal : will it count as rejection?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, schengen-visas, visa-refusal-appeal

I got my Schengen visa after appealing against rejection. So effectively rejection was overruled.

Now many countries ask if your visa has ever been rejected during a visa application, and I am wondering if this needs to be mentioned.

I see the situation as visa granted for an application via appeal, hence final state is no rejection. Any thoughts?

Comment: Better to declare and explain would be my thoughts

Comment: In any case, it would probably depend on the country you are applying for a visa for, and their wording of the question and/or of the relevant laws/regulations, so I don’t think it’s possible to provide a blanket answer, other than the safe one, say yes and explain. And of course it matters only for countries which ask about refusals in any other country.

Comment: You might want to read [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/110907/12065).

Comment: From which country you got your visa after appeal and in how much time ?