# Can a UK visa ban affect an Ireland visa application?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, deception

I was issued a 10-year ban by the UK 4 years ago. Unfortunately, I answered no to the question of 'Have you been refused a UK visa before?' . It was a genuine error on my part when I was filling out the online visa form as I have gotten several UK visas even after refusals before.

1. Is there any likelihood of getting a UK visitor visa if I reapply? Or what can I do to overturn the ban?
2. Can the UK ban affect my getting an Irish tourist visa in any way?

Comment: The UK would not entertain your application for a visitor visa, as you have a ban. The UK and Ireland share information under the Common Travel Area (CTA) agreement, and there is a probability an Irish visa application could fail as you have to disclose the UK ban. Were you not do so, an Irish refusal on your immigration record would add another very bad mark against you.

Comment: @Giorgio I don't believe it's necessary to disclose the ban, just the refusal.

Answer (score 10):

Of course the UK ban **can** affect your Irish application. Ireland asks if you have ever been denied a visa, and you will presumably tell the truth this time, so they will take that into account in their decisionmaking.

Regarding the first part of your question, see [What can I do to lift a 10 year ban for making a mistake in my UK visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64097/what-can-i-do-to-lift-a-10-year-ban-for-making-a-mistake-in-my-uk-visa-applicati) -- the attempt will be expensive and it is unlikely to work.