# uk student visa ban for 10 years due to lack of fund

Tags: uk, ireland, visa-bans

I have been banned from the UK until February 2021 when I applied for a student visa in 2011 and was refused entry. This was due to a lack of fund in my account.

The money was deposited by my agent on my behalf and he withdrew it after a week without my knowledge. When they enquired my account they found I was not true with my bank details, and I have been banned from the UK automatically for 10 years.

Now I am planning to apply for a Irish visa. Will the ban affect my application?

Comment: The real answer is **nobody knows**. Your ban was for misrepresentation, not lack of funds.

Comment: After looking on Travel.SE, I think this is a partial duplicate of [Can a UK visa ban affect an Ireland visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/119497/can-a-uk-visa-ban-affect-an-ireland-visa-application)

Comment: To clarify @HonoraryWorldCitizen's comment, you were refused your visa for having a lack of funds. That on its own wouldn't have got you a ban; the ban was because your agent's actions made your application a lie.

Comment: The only way you could have been given the ban was if the bank accounts were false. What does the refusal say? Even if the agent withdrew the money after you submitted the statement, it could only have been false if it was not a true representation of the bank account on that day. Otherwise removing money from the account after submission is not deception.

Comment: It's more likely that the agent never put the funds into your account in the first place. He wouldn't have been able to remove funds without your permission. It's more likely he altered the statement without any transaction.

Comment: You don't get banned for ten years for lack of funds. You get banned for ten years for *dishonesty*. If you were refused for lack of funds, you can reapply as soon as you get the necessary funds and have the necessary funds provenance. If you were banned for dishonesty, more funds in and of themselves won't help - it makes you a rich liar instead of a poor liar.

Answer (score 3):

The real answer is nobody knows. Your ban was for misrepresentation, not lack of funds.

Any immigration ban anywhere (actually any adverse immigration history anywhere) can affect other visa applications.This is particularly true and more likely for country’s whose  application forms specifically ask about previous bans/deportation/refusals in other countries.

Some country’s applications do not ask about adverse history elsewhere so your previous transgressions elsewhere may never come up.

Because Ireland and UK are so tightly coupled, I would put your case in the **more likely** category especially when the ban is not spent. Would be better chances perhaps if you allow the ban to run out.