# Banned from Ireland for 5 years, want to visit UK with my husband

Tags: uk, ireland, visa-bans, deception

I was banned from Ireland for 5 years for deception in 2015. My husband (principal) and I want to apply for UK tourist visa this year 2019. I hope being banned from Ireland will not jeopardized our chances of getting visa to UK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a UK visa ban affect an Ireland visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/119497/can-a-uk-visa-ban-affect-an-ireland-visa-application)

Comment: @Giorgio:  that previous thread asks about the opposite situation, where someone previously banned from the UK wants to visit Ireland.  The answer may be similar, but it's not obvious that it is.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert you're absolutely right; I got my circuits crossed.. I've withdrawn the close vote. TY.

Comment: or just wait until Brexit

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I’m afraid your hopes will be dashed because you will have to declare your ban in any UK visa application. UKVI takes previous travel history into account when assessing applications, a ban for deception makes it unlikely your application would be successful. In case it helps, you should be aware that the UK and Ireland share immigration data https://www.ein.org.uk/news/home-office-share-immigration-data-ireland-under-new-memorandum-understanding

Comment: If you tell the truth about the Irish ban, your request for an UK visa will *probably* be denied. If you lie, the request will *almost certainly* be denied and you might face an UK ban as well.

Comment: @Hannah This SE:Expatriates thread *https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15635/10-year-uk-visa-ban-would-it-affect-visa-application-to-eire#comment27026_15635* also addresses the UK/Ireland relationship, and information that's shared between them.

Comment: @David,  I hope this ban will not affect Schengen countries and America. Thank you

Comment: @Hannah You might also review this SE:Travel page: *https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56986/do-the-governments-of-united-kingdom-and-usa-share-immigration-data#56988*

Comment: @Hannah Ireland is not yet connected to the Schengen Information System (SIS) https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen-information-system_en so your ban may not affect a Schengen visa unless the application process requires you to declare it.

Comment: @Traveller, now I understand better.  Thank you

Comment: In any case, also if they would not share data, you should never lie on visa and immigration application. You already have a ban for deception, things could go out of control quickly. [and in future they could share past data, considering the actual paranoia on security... consider that]

Comment: Looks like you only have to wait a year anyway. Why not do that, rather than perform some action that's liable to leave a record that continues (or even expands) the problem?

Comment: @T.E.D. 1 year until the ban expires, but probably quite a bit longer than that until there are no repercussions (certainly as far as the Common Travel Area goes).