# Visa refued for not disclosing 12 years old Rejection from Uk

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, visa-bans

[image]I applied for a UK visitor visa, I thought I had all my document straight forward disclosing all required information. When it came to question have you been rejected Visa, I was wrongly adviced by many applicants who got the visa to  only list past 10 years since the older rejection is automatically erased from the system. Mind that I was trying to be extremely sincere with my answer and I mentioned my visa rejection to the US. AFter applying I got a rejection letter that I was a Fraud and I got a ten years Ban, it was mentioned that I withhold the information trying to deceive them. I was shocked by their reply. If I was a fraud, by all means, I would not even disclose the US visa Rejection. There is no room for Appeal unfortunately but this is unjust and harsh. I do not know if anyone had a simmilar situation and on top of that I did not have that passport nor the information regarding that rejection since my family applied for that visa and I had no idea why we were rejected nor the exact dates. anyone manage to solve similar situation.

Comment: The question is ‘Have you EVER been refused...”, there is no mention of within the last 10 years. It doesn’t matter that you didn’t remember why.

Comment: If you post a copy of the refusal letter with your personal details blanked out you may get a better answer. Possible duplicate of [What can I do to lift a 10 year ban for making a mistake in my UK visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64097/what-can-i-do-to-lift-a-10-year-ban-for-making-a-mistake-in-my-uk-visa-applicati)

Comment: I should not have listened to other people advice, and funny enough they all had the visa and did the same thing, I accept the rejection but the 10 years ban is harsh, and I want to travel around the world and i do not want this to harm my application for other countreis. I am An Iranian Citizen so that adds up to everything. i have been to other countries including shengen. I also mentioned in my application if there are any areas that you need more clarification kindly contant me(there are no more interviews)

Comment: I know that my brother applied for all the family visa, I did not know the year till, i received the rejection letter(i thought it was 2006. it says that I can apply again but will be rejected unless my circumstances changes. Shall I submite the application again and submitte all my pass 15 years passport. i applied a month ago.

Comment: At this point there is virtually no chance for you to get a UK visa without the help of a solicitor. See the linked post for further information and links to where to find reputable solicitors.

Comment: @Farzi There is no point reapplying, you will not get a visa. Read the answer to the duplicate question - your only hope is to consult an Immigration lawyer, but the chances of success are slim to zero.

Comment: Thanks Michael,  that is fine with me not being granted a UK visa, US simply told me they are not convinced that i would return, they even told me try again(which was a week befor trump Ban), so didnot try again, i always choose the best timing to travel :P. I guess UK is more restrict. i think getting a solictor is stupid, it was simply a toursit purpose driven visa, if i had family that i couldnot see for ten years becuase of this that would change the circumestances. As i said i just want to be heard. Maybe one day the world get some peace .