# I overstayed my post study work Visa and was removed from the UK with a 2 year ban. How can this be overturned

Tags: visas, uk, visa-bans

I overstayed my Post study work Visa (having lived and worked in the UK legally for 8years)  because I had just been divorced and didn't have the wherewithal to immediately relocate to in my home country (Nigeira)

I was removed from the UK voluntarily and given a 2 year ban but when I applied for a visiting Visa 1.5 years later, I was told my ban is for 10 years.

How do I overturn this BAN?

Comment: The only feasible options are consult an Immigration lawyer or wait 10 years. Possible duplicate of [What can I do to lift a 10 year ban for making a mistake in my UK visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64097/what-can-i-do-to-lift-a-10-year-ban-for-making-a-mistake-in-my-uk-visa-applicati)

Comment: 2 or 10 year ban? If it is two, legal system could take much of that time, so it is not worth (OTOH the removal will affect visa on other countries). As student, it is assumed that you knew about our overstaying. Note: if you had good reasons (but so you already told them) things are different (e.g. unable to move).

Comment: "...given a 2 year BAN but when I applied for a visiting Visa 1.5years later..." Why did you apply for a visa when you knew you were banned? Did you declare everything you were asked truthfully on your application?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but don’t waste your time and moneys to try to overturn this ban. Even if some attorney gets it overturned it will cost you a fortune.

Forget U.K. for now.