# My UK Visa V3.6 Refusals looks a little different

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, visa-bans, student-visas, deception

**Here’s a summary of my immigration history:**

I applied for my brother’s wedding in 2019 which was to be held in the UK. I applied for a visit visa and got the notice posted. My other family members reapplied and got their visas. I lost interest in going altogether so I didn’t

Apparently, my mother (who didn’t remember she did) applied for a students visa on my behalf when I was a minor. I didn’t know the details of the applications/refusals, I didn’t have records of it and I went ahead and stated I have never been refused visa before.

I want to reapply for my student visa(MSC, I lived in another country for almost 10years) in 2023, I am not sure if I have already been banned because it makes no statement as to the ban already counting from this application, school fees has been paid in full, I have my POF and a [cover letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boP4K.jpg) explaining I was a minor, so I couldn’t have known, I am older, married and not going to be a nuisance.

> REASONS FOR REFUSAL
> You have applied for a visa to visit the UK.
>
> In deciding whether you meet the requirements of Appendix V: Immigration Rules for visitors
> (https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/immigration-rules), I have
> considered:
>
> - Your application document
> - Your immigration history
>
> ### The decision
>
> I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not
> satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph(s) V3.6 of
> Appendix V: Immigration Rules for Visitors because:
>
> • Under paragraph V3.6 of the Immigration Rules, a person must
> automatically be refused entry clearance if false representations or
> documents are used (whether or not material to the application and
> whether or not to the applicant's knowledge), or material facts are
> not disclosed in relation to the application. A false representation
> for these purposes is a lie, or a false statement in a visa
> application, made either orally or in writing. A false document
> includes:
>
> - A genuine document which has been altered or tampered with;
> - A counterfeit document (one that is completely false);
> - A genuine document which is being used by an impostor;
> - A genuine document which has been fraudulently obtained or issued;
> - A genuine document which contains a falsified or counterfeit visa endorsement.
>
> The Immigration Office
>
> You stated in your application that you have never been refused a visa
> for any country including the UK. However, checks have confirmed that
> you were refused three previous times on 27/08/2009 re: DUBAI/621417,
> on 22/09/2009 re: passports ABDB/322524, and on 03/11/2009 re:
> ABDB/329335. I am satisfied that you have made false representations
> and submitted a false document in support of your application. Your
> application is therefore refused under V3.6 of the Immigration Rules
> after referral to an Entry Clearance Manager.
>
> ### Future Applications
>
> Any future UK visa applications you make will be considered on their
> individual merits; however, you are likely to be refused unless the
> circumstances of your application change.
>
> In relation to this decision, there is no right of appeal or right to
> administrative review.
>
> You should note that because this application for entry clearance has
> been refused under paragraph V3.6 of the Immigration Rules, any future
> applications may also be refused for the same reason, under paragraph
> 320 (7B) of the Immigration Rules or paragraph V3.7 of Appendix V of
> the Immigration Rules.
>
> A refusal under paragraph V3.7 of the Immigration Rules may attract an
> automatic refusal period of up to 10 years. The period starts from the
> date of the previous event in which the deception or submission of
> falsified documents or information was employed.

Should I do it? Was I banned for 10years? I don’t know what false document they referred to, did they mean the application itself was false? Everyone around me isn’t clear on what is going on. Should I wait till 2029

Comment: I can see someone forgetting that they applied for a visa once, but your mother forgetting that she applied and was refused three times within 10 weeks seems a little suspicious.

Answer (score 5):

You are not banned but if you apply you will almost certainly be refused and banned until 10 years after your 2019 refusal [Suitability: false representations, deception, false documents, non- disclosure of relevant facts](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1160299/Suitability_false_representations.pdf) Even after that period expires, you may not be given a visa.

Although you were a minor at the time of the previous applications, you would have had to give your biometrics as part of the application process. It’s quite a stretch to see how your mother could forget that she applied for a student visa on your behalf and was refused *three times within 10 weeks*, and that you were completely unaware of the refusals. If you definitely want to apply, IMHO you should get advice from a qualified immigration lawyer.

Comment: @Mrs Ash I fully agree with Traveller's answer. I encourage you to read "qualified immigration lawyer" to mean a solicitor or barrister located in and licensed by the UK.

Comment: So this is the thing, my dad had just died (they were married 30yrs), that entire year to my mum and I was a blur. I did biometrics but I honestly forgot. Until this letter, I didn’t remember. This was 10years ago as at 2019, I can’t remember what I had for breakfast a week ago. My whole family lives there, I have nieces and nephews I have never met because I can’t get in, 10years is too long a punishment. is there no way I can explain that this was an honest oversight not an attempt to defraud? I have never been in trouble with the law in all my years of traveling

Comment: @MrsAsh I don’t mean to sound harsh but pretty much everyone caught out by not disclosing a previous refusal will claim it was ‘an honest oversight’. Eg https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64097/what-can-i-do-to-lift-a-10-year-ban-for-making-a-mistake-in-my-uk-visa-applicati If you want to meet your nieces & nephews the easiest option would be to have them visit you, and/or you can talk to an immigration lawyer (expensive), and/or wait it out.